# Gunicorn won't start Flask app because "Failed to parse 'app' as an attribute name or function call."

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to run Flask app locally in the docker and I'm facing the following problem

app.py:

```
class App:
    '''Base flask app'''

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
    
    @property
    def flask_app(self) -> Flask:
        '''Return flask app'''

        return self.app

app_instance = App()
```

My Dockerfile:

```
...
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :8080 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:app_instance.app
```

Error:

```
Failed to parse 'app_instance.app' as an attribute name or function call.
```